# When I format my USB drive in NTFS, it creates a "System Volume Information" folder – is it a virus?

Tags: windows-xp, usb

I tried to format my 2GB USB drive in NTFS in Windows XP.

It was formatted successfully, but on the formatted drive one of the folders is named **"System Volume Information"**. I tried to delete the folder, it says **"Access Denied"** also safely remove my USB drive, but it shows an error like "the Generic Volume is used in another program...".

Why does this happen? Is the folder "System Volume Information" a virus? How can I overcome this problem?

Answer (score 7):

A "System Volume Information" folder is created every time a drive is formatted. It's a Windows OS hidden system folder, and it is of no threat to your PC.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Cebrilung, but i format the USB drive in another system, there is no system volume information folder.

Comment: See: [What's the deal with the System Volume Information folder?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2003/11/20/55764.aspx)

Comment: It's likely that the system you are seeing the folder show up on has hidden / protected files set to visible. By default you won't see it, but it takes about 3 clicks to make them visible.